# android picasso clear cache

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using Picasso to show one's portrait, when the protrait is changed, I want to clear this user's cache(or all users' portrait cache), here is my code, and it doesn't work,anyone can help me?

```
LruCache lruCache = new LruCache(context);
lruCache.clear();
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).memoryCache(lruCache).build();
picasso.load(portraitUrl).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().error(R.drawable.user_portrait).into(portaitView);
```

Comment: Here is your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso

Answer (score 8):

In the recent versions of Picasso, there is a new method for invalidate, without any workarounds, so I think that custom PicassoTools class mentioned earlier, is now obsolete

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and none of the solutions was acceptable for me... So I at least made a solution with reflection. I don't use crop, resize and so on, so my clear function only works if you only use `load(url)` with resizing, cropping, transformations... But I customized the complete `getKey` function, so this should at least be a big help to extend the clear function. Or just make the `getKey`function public and change the `clear(uri)` function to `clear(key)`...

I just copied the key function from the source code and adopted it.

*Just get the picasso instance from my tools class and everything should work (instead of having an context provider like me, you can for example add a init function, to initialise the PicassoTools class, with for example the application context).*

Just use the following tools class:

```
public class PicassoTools
{
private static Picasso picasso = null;
private static CustomLruCache lruCache = null;

private static CustomLruCache getCache()
{
    if (lruCache == null)
        lruCache = new CustomLruCache(MainApp.getAppContext());
    return lruCache;
}

public static Picasso getPicasso()
{
    if (picasso == null)
        picasso = new Picasso.Builder(MainApp.getAppContext()).memoryCache(getCache()).build();
    return picasso;
}

public static void clear(Uri uri)
{
    getCache().remove(getKey(uri));
}

public static void clearCache()
{
    getCache().clear();
    // Picasso.with(MainApp.getAppContext()).cache.clear();
}

public static void clearCache(Context c)
{
    getCache().clear();
    // Picasso.with(c).cache.clear();
}

private static final int KEY_PADDING = 50; // Determined by exact science.

private static String getKey(Uri uri)
{
    return getKey(uri, null, 0, 0, false, false, null);
}

private static String getKey(Uri uri, Integer resourceId, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, boolean centerCrop, boolean centerInside, List<Transformation> transformations)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (uri != null)
    {
        String path = uri.toString();
        builder.ensureCapacity(path.length() + KEY_PADDING);
        builder.append(path);
    }
    else
    {
        builder.ensureCapacity(KEY_PADDING);
        builder.append(resourceId);
    }
    builder.append('\n');

    if (targetWidth != 0)
    {
        builder.append("resize:").append(targetWidth).append('x').append(targetHeight);
        builder.append('\n');
    }
    if (centerCrop)
    {
        builder.append("centerCrop\n");
    }
    else if (centerInside)
    {
        builder.append("centerInside\n");
    }

    if (transformations != null)
    {
        // noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
        for (int i = 0, count = transformations.size(); i < count; i++)
        {
            builder.append(transformations.get(i).key());
            builder.append('\n');
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

And the extended cache class:

```
public class CustomLruCache extends LruCache
{
public CustomLruCache(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CustomLruCache(int value)
{
    super(value);
}

@Override
public Bitmap get(String key)
{
    L.d(this, key);
    return super.get(key);
}

public void remove(String key)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap value = map.remove(key);

        Field fieldSize = LruCache.class.getDeclaredField("size");
        fieldSize.setAccessible(true);
        Integer size = (Integer) fieldSize.get(this);
        size -= Utils.getBitmapBytes(value);
        fieldSize.set(this, size);

        Field fieldEvictionCount = LruCache.class.getDeclaredField("evictionCount");
        fieldEvictionCount.setAccessible(true);
        Integer evictionCount = (Integer) fieldEvictionCount.get(this);
        evictionCount++;
        fieldEvictionCount.set(this, evictionCount);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        L.e(this, e);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        L.e(this, e);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
        L.e(this, e);
    }
}
}
```

PS: inspired by [Invalidate cache in Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso)