# How does facebook or instagram app retain images or data after entering the app with no internet connection?

Tags: android, offline-caching

In Facebook app, for example, I login with my internet connection. Then I close the app, turn off the internet and close all my system tabs. Then even though my internet connection is off, I see the images and data that had been previously loaded still retained.

How does Facebook app do that? What should I do if wanted to implement such a feature in my Android app?

Comment: The images are cached and saved to disk, then shown instead of always requested by a network request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load images from disk cache with Picasso if offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391523/load-images-from-disk-cache-with-picasso-if-offline)

Comment: @HiteshSahu my friend its not duplicate completely because he wants to cache/store data too, not only images.

Comment: have you got your answer ? because  from below answers they all are talking about image caching only . no one mentioned data part in that .

Comment: Hey Shababb have u got any answer ? if yes please let me know.

Comment: @TusharLathiya I feel like there are many solutions to how Facebook and Instagram cache images. `Picasso` and `Glide` are two libraries that automatically cache images. `Retrofit` with `OkHttp` can be used to cache responses and you can always make a custom caching mechanism with local db using `Room`

Comment: Thanks for reply @ShababbKarim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use 'Picasso' Library for caching, loading... images from internet  :

http://square.github.io/picasso/

> Automatic memory and disk caching

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .resize(50, 50)
   .centerCrop()
   .into(imageView)
```

for data, you can store data using `shared preferences` for small stuff or a local database like `sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

You can cache these images ( saving them locally ) - there are multiple ways to do so. Some image loading libraries are doing this - or you can do this on the transport-layer ( e.g. with okhttp )

Comment: Could you please give me a link or a hint on how cache these images?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many image caching libraries. Such as Picasso,Volley,Universal image loader and so on.Refer these links.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Simply they have disk cache, if you open Facebook Android App and go Open Source Libraries part you will see they using [DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache) . And if you check Facebook App size in Applications its growing everyday. Also you can use mobile database like [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) or [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/) etc.