# How to manage offline data in android like facebook and instagram does

Tags: android, database, caching, offline

I know similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328894/how-does-facebook-or-instagram-app-retain-images-or-data-after-entering-the-app) .but they only answered image caching perspective.So My request is to please go through whole question before announcing it duplicate .

My question is :

when we open Facebook or Instagram app with internet connection On , data is loaded to the app, after that in  offline mode It is still visible into app.I'm developing similar application (with Social feed ,likes ,comments ) and want to clear my confusion about offline perspective.

I'm confused with these following points ...

1. My concern is not about images , I know how to retrieve images in ofline 
   mode. my question is about data (like comments count , likes count , your 
   friend comment on top ). they even managed to do this inside another 1 to 2 
   activities (if you click on comment , you can see minimum 5-6 comments loaded 
   also).
2. may be they are not caching it because when we clear cache , its still 
   there (I'm not sure ,just my observation.) . so they are handling some kind 
   of database paradigm .
3. If we want to choose database .  I don't think we can manage to store all posts with its respective comments ,likes all in SQLite or Realm or Room.

I want to clear these points and i think many developers like me also . so It would be very helpful for me if you just show me a way or guide me through.

Comment: These data are stored in local DB. You can clear data based on the timestamp let's say like delete all posts and its related info if they are older than a month

Comment: @Tejas  how can you manage all that stuff with table structure .lets say for one day. 100 posts , each post with 50 comments , 100 likes . and at the time of fetching . whole data with proper relation in SQlite , Realm ?

Comment: did you find your answer ? if yes then please share

Comment: @SharartiKAKA  no . I haven't found yet.

Comment: It must be using local db only for this purpose. And to answer your question about fetching whole data, it uses pagination approach to fetch only the first 10 posts/5 comments at a time so that it won't take much time to fetch any post or comment

Comment: @VipulK.Patil. my concern was not about pagination but no prob i got my answer . They are networking library which provide caching mechanism like retrofit or okHttp.

Comment: Cool. No issues. Just curious to know, is it reliable than storing the data in the local DB? I mean does it still give you cached response even if the network bandwidth is super low, or no connectivity?

Comment: @VipulK.Patil problem wih local DB is . you have to design all the tables and columns mechanism . storing data , fetching data ..blah blah. In case of caching these all tasks will be managed by network library. Bandwidth wont be any issue.