# Android Cardview with picasso, recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, staggeredgridlayout

i'm new in this forum.
I have a problem with CardView.
I use recyclerview to binding data and to show a big list of image using picasso with staggeredgridlayoutmanager.
But when i scroll the view, the image refresh (naturally), the cards change position and return to original dimension, sometimes disappear.
is there a solution?
and how i use the cache to save the images that i load with picasso?

this is the code:

```
public final static class BusStopViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mImage;

    private WeakReference<OnItemClickListener> mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference;

    /**
     * This is the interface to implement to listen to the click on the item
     */
    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        /**
         * Invoked when we select a bus stop
         *
         * @param position The selected position
         */
        void onItemClicked(int position);

        }

        Context context;

        public BusStopViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            mImage = ViewUtility.findViewById(itemView, R.id.country_photo);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * We use this to register a specific OnItemClickListener
         *
         * @param onItemClickListener The OnItemClickListener
         */
        public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            Log.e("setOnItemClickListener", "true");
            this.mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference = new WeakReference<OnItemClickListener>(onItemClickListener);

            if (this.mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference == null)
                Log.e("setOnItemClickListener", "null");
        }

        /**
         * This binds the model to the View
         *
         * @param image The model to map
         */
        private LruCache<String, ImageView> mMemoryCache;
        private int flag = 0;

        public void bind(Image image, int position) {

            Picasso.with(context).load(image.url).fit().centerInside().into(mImage); //todo risolvere gestione eventi
            mImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        }



    public final static class BusStopAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BusStopViewHolder> implements BusStopViewHolder.OnItemClickListener {

        /**
         * The model for the Adapter
         */
        private List<Image> mModel;

        /**
         * The Reference to the Listener for BusStop selection
         */
        private WeakReference<OnImageStopListener> mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference;


        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int position) {
            Log.e("onItemClicked 1", "true");
            OnImageStopListener listener;
            if (this.mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference != null && (listener = this.mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference.get()) != null) {
                Log.e("OnItemCLicked 2", "true");
                listener.onBusStopClicked(mModel.get(position), position);

            }

        }

        /**
         *

     This is the interface to implement to listen to the click on the item
             */
        public interface OnImageStopListener {

            /**
             * Invoked when we select a bus stop
             *
             * @param busStop  The selected BusStop
             * @param position The selected position
             */
            void onBusStopClicked(Image busStop, int position);

        }

        /**
         * Creates a BusStopAdapter for the given model
         *
         * @param model The model for this Adapter
         */
        Context context;

        BusStopAdapter(final List<Image> model, Context context) {
            this.mModel = model;
            this.context = context;
        }

    /**
     * We use this to register a specific OnBusStopListener
     *
     * @param onImageStopListener The OnBusStopListener
     */ 
    public void setOnBusStopListener(final OnImageStopListener onImageStopListener) {
        Log.e("setOnBusStopListener", "true");
        this.mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference = new WeakReference<OnImageStopListener>(onImageStopListener);

        if (this.mOnItemClickListenerWeakReference.get() == null)
            Log.e("setOnBusStopListener", "null");
        else Log.e("setOnBusStopListener", "NOT null");
    }

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public BusStopViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // We inflate the data and return the related ViewHolder
        final View layout = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.simple_img_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new BusStopViewHolder(layout, context);    
    }

    int j = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BusStopViewHolder busStopViewHolder, int position) {

        busStopViewHolder.bind(mModel.get(position), position);
        busStopViewHolder.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setData(List<Image> mModel) {
        this.mModel = mModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mModel.size();
    }
}
```

this is the xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp"

    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/country_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="0dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_design_support_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/ciao"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_botton_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/material_botton_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="#00FF00"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: in default Picasso save cache of all the images.. if app is not destroyed  picasso don't download image twice ...

Comment: but, when i scoll the cardview, they return to orignial dimension and move themeselves, how set the dimension of cardview with the image's dimension, and why the cardview moves when i scroll???

Comment: *The cardview move columns when i scroll

Answer (score 0):

1.You should use Glide by Google

2.If possible, You should define the height and width of the image (View and Image).

3.Use placeholder for Image

4.If you don't have a link for the image, you should set null for ImageView.

P.s: please, post your code here.

Comment: 1. Try this  https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

2. Picasso will automatically cache the image

3. You should try 4 solutions above

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use the cache to reload the image in the recyclerview withouth request to server?

Comment: follow this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391523/load-images-from-disk-cache-with-picasso-if-offline