# get bitmap after picasso sets image to an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso, offline-caching

I'm trying to save downloaded images in shared preferences in base64 format so that the app can work offline. I've used picasso

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(urls.get(position)).into(imageView);
```

I request the server with a specific category of images and the server responds with a json containing the urls of those images. I found picasso to do this job for me as i need to write my async task for this.The images are loaded into ImageViews of a gridview image adapter.

What I want to do is that as soon as the image is loaded through the url using this function I want that bitmap image so that I can save it in shared preferences or serialize it something so that it can be used offline.
or suggest me a better solution.

Comment: Picasso has offline cache option. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34051356/1512199)

Comment: I found this
    
    Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(url)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .into(imageView);

but

    error: cannot find symbol variable NetworkPolicy

Comment: cannot resolve method networkPolicy()

Comment: Solved it. My picasso version was old. i updated it. it's solved. Thankyou so much <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .into(imageView);
```

Thankyou so much guys <3