# Picasso not loading image from cache

Tags: android, picasso

I am currently using latest "stable" picasso 2.5.2 because of some other library which has not yet updated to latest one. The issue i am experiencing is that Picasso is unnable to load image on some devices when offline.

I am loading with

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(myImage).into(artWindow);
```

i tried with checking if its offline and than forcing with

```
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
```

i also tried to just include okhttp in gradle and it still didnt work especially on xperia device. Majority of devices works perfect. Anyone had simmilar problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391523/load-images-from-disk-cache-with-picasso-if-offline

Comment: Thanks will try, i think there is more problem with device than anything with picasso :)