# My application is eating too much storage data&cache

Tags: android, caching, storage

I recently developed a RSS reader for Android. I'm using SAXParser to parse some XMLs and Picasso library to display images.
The problem is that after using the application for some time, in App info it shows me huge amount of Storage data and Cache being "eaten". Now it shows me Storage Total: 9,05MB, Application: 4,78MB, Data: 4,27MB, Cache: 11,91MB. The cache&data are getting bigger each time I use the app.
Can Android handle this by itself or do I have to clear cache manually from the source code of my app? I don't know why data is getting bigger as I don't find normally to programatically erase data.

Comment: I have never use Picasso but I would start there. There is probably a flag to enable/disable in relation to image caching.

Comment: There is a method to clear Picasso's cache but I don't know how to implement it (I've seen it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso). How can I add something to a .jar file?