# How to clear Picasso's cache for a specific url?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to find out how can I clear cache of a specific URL or make Picasso notice for the server side's image change. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why do you write with "CamelCase" style? :)

Comment: ah i keep being told about it :)

Comment: Have you tried [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso)? Picasso.with(ctx).load(new File("/path/to/image")).skipMemoryCache().into(imageView)

Comment: yes, this skips memory cache just for once, after a refresh, and trying without the skipmemorycache again, it loads from cache again, it doesnt replace it

Comment: You can't. But we're going to add it: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438

Comment: Thanks for Your nice Lib Jake,Its Amazing how a genius like You lost this option ;) may i ask how long untill then?

Comment: Please stop using camel case for your posts, @reza. Writing styles that are difficult to read cause other people work. Since you've admitted to having being told about it before, I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

[Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton) replied [on Dec 12, 2014](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438#issuecomment-66708967) that the best candidate solution to be in 2.5 milestone is:

```
picasso.load('http://example.com/')
  .cachePolicy(NO_CACHE, NO_STORE)
  .networkPolicy(NO_CACHE, NO_STORE, OFFLINE)
  .into(imageView);

enum MemoryPolicy {
  NO_CACHE, NO_STORE
}
enum NetworkPolicy {
  NO_CACHE, NO_STORE, OFFLINE
}
```

**update**

or now you can use:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);
```

as answered by [mes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016092/mes) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524578/905801)

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from Jake Wharton.*

You can't [do this]. But we're going to add it: github.com/square/picasso/issues/438