# clear cache of Picasso in android?

Tags: android

How to clear cache of Picasso library?

```
Picasso.with(mActivity).load("http://"+AppConstants.IPAddress+"/MenupicsServices/UserPhotos/"+DataSource.GetValue(mActivity, AppConstants.Save_UserDetails, AppConstants.User_Profile_Photo))
     .resize(120, 120)
     .skipMemoryCache()
     .into(Img_User_Profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        Picasso.with(context).cache.clear();
```

For Further reference see this.
[Invalidate cache in Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso)

Mark as up, if it works for you. :)

Comment: But for me after this Picasso.with(context) the cache attribute is not there. Can you please mention any other way to cleat the cache