# Fresco add Bitmap to Cache programmatically

Tags: android, bitmap, fresco

I am uploading an image to my server and once uploaded my server responds with the new URI for it (can be the same URL as the old one), I want to remove the old cached image and insert the new one for the new URI.

I try to accomplish this by doing:

```
// Retrofit2 onResponse

String newImageUri = response.body().getUri();
String oldImageUri = Preferences.getUser().getImageUrl();   

// Remove old image from cache
Fresco.getImagePipeline().evictFromCache(Uri.parse(oldImageUri));               
Fresco.getImagePipeline().evictFromDiskCache(Uri.parse(oldImageUri));
Fresco.getImagePipeline().evictFromMemoryCache(Uri.parse(oldImageUri));
Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getMainFileCache().remove(new SimpleCacheKey(oldImageUri));

// Insert new image at new URI
try {
    Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getMainFileCache().insert(new SimpleCacheKey(newImageUri), new WriterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            os.write(imageData); // byte[] or the new Bitmap
        }
    });
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
uriProfileImage.setImageURI(newImageUri);
```

There are no exceptions but I still only see the old image.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256786/2910520) answer they have used the .remove() method calling them from `getImagePipelineFactory().[from_to_delete].remove(...)` while you are using the evict ones. You could try with this and see if helps (maybe will not work for you because the answer is 2 years old and Fresco library probably has changed something in the meantime)

Comment: @MatPag I did see that answer, clearly it doesnt work for me.

Comment: You said you only see the old image. How did you test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, it was an error with the Uri format for the new Uri...

Comment: Another worthwhile note: If you are loading ImageView within a RecyclerView.ViewHolder -> you need to ensure the first line you call in OnBindViewHolder is to set imageview source to null. This ensures the image is not reused from the pool.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://frescolib.org/static/fresco-logo.png");
Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getMainDiskStorageCache().remove(new CacheKey(uri.toString()));
Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getSmallImageDiskStorageCache().remove(new CacheKey(uri.toString()));
```