# Loading ImageView from URL Android

Tags: java, android

I am using [ImageGallery](https://github.com/lawloretienne/ImageGallery) to display some images in my app, in this example the images are being saved (cached), and I dont want them to be so I have found that the images are loaded in on this adapter class [Adapter](https://github.com/lawloretienne/ImageGallery/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/etiennelawlor/imagegallery/library/adapters/ImageGalleryAdapter.java)  with this code

```
private void setUpImage(ImageView iv, String imageUrl) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        Picasso.with(iv.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .resize(mGridItemWidth, mGridItemHeight)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(iv);
    } else {
        iv.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

Which is called every time the gallery is displayed, what I can't figure out is why they do not get reloaded if you go back to this page?

How can I make so that every time this page load the images are reloaded?

Thanks

Comment: Picasso caches the images, you should clear the cache with `Picasso.with(context).invalidate();` after this, the images should be fetched from the url again (instead of from cache).

Comment: @Mdlc thank you very much, and should this code go at the end of the load? Im also get a compile error `cannot resolve invalidate()`? What should go inside?

Comment: You should call this before making a new load (e.g. if you reload the list from onResume() you would first call .invalidate() on picasso)

Comment: @Mdlc okay and what does in the `()` of invalidate it says it take a `path`, `file` or `URI`?

Comment: You're right, my code only applied to a previous version of the library. Check the following answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23544650/1683141