# Profile Image Uploader and Load it with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have an android app which has profile image.
The user can edit his/her profile image.
I'm using Picasso to load images, but every time I load profile image, Picasso loads old image.

When I upload profile image I don't change it's url, so profile image url for every user is constant.

First question: should I change profile image url every time user change profile image?

Second question: When user change his/her profile image I invalidate Picasso to load new image using this code:

```
picassoInstance.load(url)
  .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
  .transform(new CircleTransform())
  .placeholder(dr)
  .into(imageView);
```

But Picasso show me the old one.
And one more thing:
I load image url into imageView without calling networkPolicy method at first.
How should I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Every Image has different name, whenever new image uploaded you have to update your image Url

**Eg. current url :** `https://photographylife.com/nikon-d810-high-resolution-image-samples`

**where Image name is :** `nikon-d810-high-resolution-image-samples`

and after uploaded new image, name will be different **for example** : `image-sample`

so you need to **update that image Url :** `https://photographylife.com/image-sample` **with new name**

try this, i telling you cause im doing the same hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

So lets just discuss one by one:

> Should I change profile image url every time user change profile
>   image?

No. You might think of other ways around. In my case, I download the picture each time the url changes with a specific name of the user (as we're considering profile picture). So when I loaded the image with Picasso I passed the file path instead of the URL so that, it won't fetch from the URL each time. Picasso doesn't do that either actually. It maintains a cache. If the file doesn't exist, just put a placeholder.

> When user change his/her profile image I invalidate Picasso to load
>   new image using this code:

I don't see any invalidate code here in your code. I would refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524578/3145960) to see how they've solved the cache problem.

> I load image url into imageView without calling networkPolicy method
>   at first.

So if you fetch the image from the external storage, I don't think there's a necessity to do so.

And another suggestion is to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) in these cases. This is almost the same thing as Picasso, but personally I like to use Glide instead of Picasso.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using Glide instead of Picasso because Glide recommended by google
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Preventing for caching in Glide

```
Glide.with(DemoActivity.this)
    .load(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(mImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to the com.squareup.picasso package.

```
package com.squareup.picasso;

public class PicassoTools {

    public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
        p.cache.clear();
    }
}
```

Because cache has package visibility, this util class can clear the cache for you. You just have to call it:

```
PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
```

Comment: I'm using picasso 2.5.2 and I can't find cache field

Answer (score 0):

I find where problem is:
I turned down disk cache but not memory cache. I should use this code:

```
picassoInstance.load(url)
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.transform(new CircleTransform())
.placeholder(dr)
.into(imageView);
```

I use this link to:
[picasso-influencing-image-caching](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-influencing-image-caching)

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate the file before loading use the code given below:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);
```

To know more details kindly study the Picasso documentation from their website.