# Picasso cache clear

Tags: android, caching, picasso, clear-cache

I already saw every solution that proposed here and nothing really works for me.

How can i clear the cache of Picasso in my app?

I've tried to use invalidate - isn't work.
I saw something about Picasso.cache.clear, but impossible to access directly to cache.

**(please don't suggest me to use NO_CACHE)**

Thanks.

Comment: can you post a sample of what you have tried with invalidate which didn't work to better understand the problem before directly jumping to other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[get from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544650/1897374)

Add this class to the com.squareup.picasso package.

```
package com.squareup.picasso;

public class PicassoTools {

    public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
        p.cache.clear();
    }
}
```

Because cache has package visibility, this util class can clear the cache for you. You just have to call it:

```
PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
```

Just add this file to a path .../java/com/squareup/picasso

*P.S. I strongly recommend use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) instead of picasso, it has more powerful features to cache control and awesome download-callbacks to catch download errors, for example*

Answer (score 0):

Update your picasso library:
`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`. 
 As `Picasso.invalidate()` only available for gradle version [2.5.0](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and above.

And to clear cache use below function:

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(file);
```