# Clear network cache using Picasso

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I'm using `Picasso` to load image into my `ImageView` like this :

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
       .load(store.getString("profile"))
       .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nothumb)
       .resize(120, 120)
       .into(iv);
```

Where `store.getString("profile") = a` string representing my url.

However even if the path don't change, when I update the image within the same path, `Picasso` still loading the previous image.

I've read that we can clear the network cache but I can't find a way to use 
`.invalidate()` method nor `.cachePolicy()` or `.networkPolicy()` when I try to use them I have unresolved symbol.

**EDIT**: I updated my `Picasso` version to compile

```
"com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
```

And now I can use `.networkPolicy()`, however I got this error I can't find any solution to fix it :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: dev.com.diaginfo, PID: 10614
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/NetworkPolicy;
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy" on path: DexPathList

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso

Comment: "i've read that we can clear the network cache but i cant find a way to use .invalidate() method nor .cachePolicy() or .networkPolicy() when i try to use them i have Unresolved Symbol."

Comment: The new error you're facing is probably caused by going over the dex limit. However, it's a completely different case and should be posted in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Picasso explicitly not to cache the image:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(store.getString("profile"))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nothumb)
    .resize(120, 120)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(iv);
```

Comment: ".cachePolicy() or .networkPolicy() when i try to use them i have Unresolved Symbol."

Comment: In which step are you trying to use them? They should work if called before `into()`.

Comment: in network policy 'P' p is in Caps. Use this   Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(store.getString("profile"))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nothumb)
    .resize(120, 120)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(iv);

Comment: My bad, was using the wrong version of Picasso i changed to 
     compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2" but have an error i cant fix see edit question

Comment: My bad, the 'p' was indeed a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Picaso use ur url as key for caching. when updating the image use a time stamp to over come this. I have used and it worked like a charm