# Reload and cache again an updated image in Picasso

Tags: java, android, caching, android-imageview, picasso

I have a link of an image in my code, which will be updated in server some times.
I load this image with Picasso library and I have two problems.

I want to show the updated image when it is changed in server and cache it again in Picasso.

First, the invalidate() method of Picasso does not invalidate disk cache memory (network cache) and the cached image in disk still show.

Second, for the first problem there are some answers in Stackoverflow such as this one: [Abort memory cache and disk cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28964219/3027833), The problem with this :it will not cache again the new image because of the policies, but I want to cache again the new image.

My app is connected to a server which I can tell the app whenever an image is changed, but the URL of images does not change.

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/28964219/1011435 ?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK Actually no:D but I read the comments and some one had said it will not cache again the image, And of course, I think he is right.
Because this solution set NO_CACHE policy for both caches.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39994358/1011435

Comment: @LordRaydenMK Nice answer. But does it cache again the image? because it uses NO_CACHE policy to to load the new image.