# How to clear Picasso cache memory in android

Tags: android, image, picasso

I have an issue with image i am trying to get images from server in list but if i update image from app it goes to server successfully but when i fetch new data  i got old image i have cleared `Picasso` cache memory still old image is display 
here is my code. is there any other solution for clear the cache of `Picasso`

```
public class WorkerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkerListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private static final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;
    private List<ItemWorkerList> itemWorkerListList;
    private Context context;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tv_worker_name, tv_worker_type;
        public CircleImageView iv_worker_image;
        public ImageView iv_worker_images;
        ImageView iv_edit_provider;
        public LinearLayout ll_doc;
        public ProgressBar pb_worker;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.setIsRecyclable(true);

            tv_worker_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_worker_name);
            tv_worker_type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_worker_type);
            iv_edit_provider = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_provider);
            iv_worker_image = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_worker_image);

            iv_edit_provider = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_provider);
            pb_worker = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pb_worker);

        }
    }


    public WorkerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemWorkerList> itemWorkerListList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemWorkerListList = itemWorkerListList;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())

                .inflate(R.layout.item_worker_list, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ItemWorkerList itemWorkerList = itemWorkerListList.get(position);
        holder.tv_worker_name.setText(itemWorkerList.getName());
        holder.tv_worker_type.setText(itemWorkerList.getCategory());

        Picasso.get().invalidate(itemWorkerList.getImage());
        Picasso.get().invalidate(itemWorkerList.getDocument());
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(itemWorkerList.getImage())) {

            Picasso.get().load(itemWorkerList.getImage()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).into(holder.iv_worker_image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    holder.pb_worker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {

                    holder.pb_worker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.dummy).into(holder.iv_worker_image);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: use skipMemoryCache this

Comment: instead of memorypolicy can i use skipMemoryCache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this -

```
Picasso.with(context).load(your_url).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .into(your_image_view);
```

Comment: try adding networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE) this too

Comment: hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Clear {

public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
    p.cache.clear();
}}
```

Use like this.

```
Clear.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
```

The class Clear must be in the package :

Because the cache is not accessible from outside that package. Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544650/4585226